# PhoneGap build fails after plugin install

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I installed this phonegap plugin: https://github.com/cranberrygame/phonegap-plugin-ad-admob

```
cordova plugin add com.cranberrygame.phonegap.plugin.ad.admob
```

but now my build now fails even after I remove it.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/var/lib/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

phonegap build android
```

here is the result:
http://pastebin.com/ZdJw3izm

this happened after installing a different plugin but was fixed after installing some extras for android like the billing library ect. but they are still installed...

Comment: Why do you try to re-build your project after plugin installation?

Comment: Ok, just created a new project and copied code over my guess the problem was that other admob plugin caused problems but now its fixed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this myself by creating a new project and copying the code over, but im not sure how to mark this question as answered...

Comment: You do not have to re-build your project after you added a plugin.